# не работает woo_pagination() WooCommerce Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Вставил `<?php woo_pagination(); ?>` после цикла в файл taxonomy-product_cat.php (файл шаблона категорий).

Выдает ошибку

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function woo_pagination()

Comment: На такой вопрос ответить невозможно. Дайте информацию: где ошибка, после чего возникает, что меняли  т.д.

Comment: Вопрос дополнил.

Comment: Ох... куда вставил - на Луну?

Comment: Вопрос дополнил

Answer (score 1):

В самом плагине WooCommerce функция `woo_pagination()` отсутствует. Она входит в так называемый WooFramework, который является составной частью некоторых платных тем, поддерживающих WooCommerce. В известных мне платных темах обнаружить WooFramework не удалось. Отсутствует он и в официальной бесплатной теме от WooCommerce - Storefront.

Код пагинации WooCommerce содержится в файле `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/loop/pagination.php`, лучше попытаться модифицировать его.

Comment: Понял, большое спасибо.